# Showing the result once

Tags: c#

I have the following code that shows my result in Messagebox but it shows each time only one ifi want to see the next one,I must click OK on message box to see the next. I want to see all result at the same time. May you comments your idea?

```
foreach (var resultwithindexss in resultss.Select((rr, iindex) => new { result2 = rr, Index = iindex }).OrderByDescending(rr => rr.result2).Take(number))
{
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: {1}", resultwithindexss.Index, resultwithindexss.result2));
}
```

PS: I tried the following code, But show no result.

```
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", resultwithindexss.Index, resultwithindexss.result2));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a console application? Try `Debug.WriteLine` instead of `Console.WriteLine`. The output should show up in the `Output` window in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you want to use `MessageBox` you have to concatenate all the results in one string before calling the `MessageBox` method.

Comment: No it is not a console appplication. @HeinA.Grønnestad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to build "big" message and then display it

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var resultwithindexss in resultss
  .Select((rr, iindex) => new { result2 = rr,  Index = iindex })
  .OrderByDescending(rr => rr.result2)
  .Take(number))
{
  sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", resultwithindexss.Index, resultwithindexss.result2));
  sb.AppendLine();
}

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're extracting every result and display it instantly instead of adding it to a string and after the loop to display it.

This should do the trick(have not tested it):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("");
foreach (var resultwithindexss in resultss.Select((rr, iindex) => new { result2 = rr, Index = iindex }).OrderByDescending(rr => rr.result2).Take(number))
{
    sb.AppendFormat(string.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", resultwithindexss.Index, resultwithindexss.result2));
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```